# Unity2D my character jump more than one when i press jump key

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics

https://pasteboard.co/IrKZbCV.png

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        float angle = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, col.contacts[0].normal);
        if (col.transform.gameObject.tag == "enemyWalk")
        {
            Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(col.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>(), GetComponent<Collider2D>(), true);
        }
        else
        {
            Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(col.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>(), GetComponent<Collider2D>(), false);
        }
        if (col.transform.gameObject.tag == "stone")
        {
            angle = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, col.contacts[0].normal);

            if (Mathf.Approximately(angle, 0))
            {
                isGround = true;
                taş = true;
            }
        }
        else if (col.transform.gameObject.tag == "ground")
        {
            angle = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, col.contacts[0].normal);

            if (Mathf.Approximately(angle, 0))
            {
                isGround = true;
                çimen = true;
            }
        }
}

    if ((isJump.jmp || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) && !isDeath && isGround)
        {
            rgd.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 2.750f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            jumpAudio.Play();
            isGround = false;
        }
```

İ want to jump my character only one times when i press jump key,but as i show this situation on picture,sometimes my character jumping too high when i jumped at near of the bottom of the rock.İ mean,as if my jump code working many times at same time.
i'm waiting for your helps.

Comment: `OnCollisionEnter` is called during `fixedUpdate`, which according to the documentation will occur no less than once per frame, but it is usually more. fixedUpdate can be called multiple times per frame. Input is polled only once per update/regular frame, so `GetKeyDown` can be true for multiple fixed updates but only one regular update. I would set a flag to jump in next update rather than handling it in your collider logic.

Comment: Sorry,how can i set a flag ? Which part of code should i change ?

Comment: I would just use a boolean value. In your collider code that you posted, pull out the logic to add force and everything else. Say we have `bool jumpFlag = false`, we set `jumpFlag = true` inside the collider function. Then in the update, `if(jumpFlag) { jumpflag= false; rgd.AddForce(......); etc}`

Comment: isGround flag already doing the same thing.i'm checking isGround true or false in my Jump code.İf true then addForce or,vice versa.

Comment: Yes but I would move what actually happens in the jump (adding force, etc) out into the update function so that it only occurs once per frame. For yours move everything out of there except setting `isGround= true`, then in the update `if(isGround) addforce, etc`

Comment: Are you sure the code is called multiple times? Why not just add a Debug.Log inside the function to be sure?